# Why does my html input type range lose active status as soon as I move it on mobile?

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"
    />
    <style>
      input[type="range"] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }

      input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 36px;
        width: 36px;
        background: #555;
        margin-top: -12px;
      }

      input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        background: blue;
      }

      input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        width: 100%;
        height: 12px;
        background: #ccc;
      }

      input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        background: #ddd;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Text
    <input type="range" style="width: 100%; -webkit-appearance: none" />
  </body>
</html>
```

In the device emulator in Chrome, when I press and hold the slider thumb it turns blue as it should, but as soon as I move it it loses the active styling. Why? And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the pseudo-class events for the input element might be missing. So try adding this and retest:

```
 input[type="range"]:visited::-webkit-slider-thumb,
 input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb,
 input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb,
 input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb
 {
    background: blue;
 }
```

Personally, I would not use "range" input types as there are way too many browsers in the recent past that never fully supported it.

Comment: I already hade :active in my code. Adding the rest as well didn't help. Quickly dragging the slider still didn't make it turn blue. But now, long-pressing made the slider turn blue, and stay blue, even after finish dragging.

Answer (score 0):

This one is not targeted to be an answer.
Just want to add an extra info for the answer of @Stokely

Not sure which mobile browser you are testing but I think you can check it here:

https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aactive

A special note from the link for non `a` element on Safari iOS:

> By default, Safari on iOS does not use the `:active` state unless there is a `touchstart` event handler on the relevant element or on the `<body>` element.

Comment: As stated in my question I'm just testing this in the device emulator in Chrome for now. But thanks for the `:active` info for iOS, that's very good to know! 